# Modifying an arrays contents starting at an index using C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to modify a char array in C using pointers for optimization. I am simply trying to set a section of the array to `0x00` faster than iterating over the array directly.

This is my current code that I'm trying. I'm trying to set indexes 65-124 to `0x00`.

```
char *paddPtr = paddedmsg; //This is needed for work earlier.
*paddPtr=&paddedmsg[65];
for (i=65; i < 125; i++, paddPtr++) {
    *paddPtr = 0x00;
}
```

There are no error messages, but the code that my professor is using to check the output is coming back as incorrect so I'm assuming there are issues, though I'm not sure exactly what the issue is.

Comment: You're doing more work than plan array access needs...

Comment: At the end of the day, you will need to scan this part of the array either way. Moreover, I am afraid that you are doing extra work too! Remember: PREMATURE OPTIMIZATION IS THE ROOT OF ALL EVIL! All caps for emphasis. :P

Comment: `memset(paddedmsg + 65, 0, 60);` should work just fine.

Comment: @Mat I've iterated over the array and set the indexes, however this is taking too long, is there a better way to speed up run time performance?

Comment: @CS2020: yes, stop using these pointers. `a[i]` is already defined by the standard as `*(a+i)`, i.e. it is doing what you're trying to emulate without the extra obfuscation you've added. (Try `memset`, might have magic inside.)

Comment: You can try `for (paddPtr = paddedmsg + 65; paddPtr < paddedmsg + 125; paddPtr++) { *paddPtr = 0; }`. First, you don't need the counter; second, did you note that I didn't use `*paddPtr=...`? This might be the problem your professor found. ALWAYS raise the warning level of your compiler to the max and get your code clean! If you like `&paddedmsg[x]` better than `paddedmsg + x` just use it. I find it more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `memset(&paddedmsg[65], 0x0, 60)` ( see https://linux.die.net/man/3/memset )